# Cross subdomain cookie handling for session?

Tags: security, cookies, subdomain

Is it possible to set an auth cookie that would be valid on:

- sub1.domain.com
- sub2.domain.com

Or will each subdomain always require it's own cookie?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use cookies across sub domains if you specify the cookie to be attached to the domain:

.domain.com

note the dot in front.

See here for reference:

http://www.jotlab.com/2008/04/08/howto-get-cookies-across-subdomains-php/

Comment: It should be noted that this does make the cookie also valid for any other subdomain of *example.com* like `sub3.example.com` and `foobar.sub1.example.com` etc.

Comment: Also you cant use secure flag by this way.

Comment: Mb Rostami - Thanks, your comment provides the information I am looking for.  Any chance you have a reference for that information?